# how to fetch inner values from Regex nested backreference

Tags: regex, perl, backreference, capturing-group

I receive input from the server in the following manner (sample input data):

```
[1284336000]: host1;event1;flag;state;counter;errors or warnings
[1284336000]: host2;event1;flag;state;counter;errors or warnings
[1284336000]: host1;event2;flag;state;counter;errors or warnings
[1284336000]: host2;event2;flag;state;counter;errors or warnings
```

I have to match the input and based on the match, create a variable with a value `hostname-eventname`.

### My Regex

```
^\[\d+\]:\s((host1);(event1)|(host2);(event2)|(host3);(event2)|(host2);(event1));(\w+);(\w+);(\d).+$
```

I want the name of the host and event separately in reference variables like `$2` or `$3`.

For example, consider this input:

```
[1284336000]: host1;event1;flag;state;counter;errors or warnings
```

I need to create a variable with a name `<hostname-eventname>` according to the hostname and eventname fetched from the match above.

Say,

```
$myVar=$2-$3  (that is, $myVar=host1-event1)
```

I cannot apply any split operation any further. So no programming: I can only read input data. And yes, the regex is of Perl regex type.

I don't know if I clarified my query or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the branch-reset operator, `(?|…|…|…)`:

```
^\[\d+\]:\s(?|(host1);(event1)|(host2);(event2)|(host3);(event2)|(host2);(event1));(\w+);(\w+);(\d).+$
```

Or more legibly:

```
m{
    ^ \[ \d+ \] : \s
    (?| (host1);(event1)  # $1, $2
      | (host2);(event2)  # $1, $2
      | (host3);(event2)  # $1, $2
      | (host2);(event1)  # $1, $2
    )
    ;
    (\w+);(\w+)           # $3, $4
    ; (\d)                # $5
    .+ $
}x
```

Comment: I’m a bit surprised nobody has picked up this. It can be a pretty important technique for certain circumstances.

Comment: True. As Jerry Pournelle likes to say, when you need it, you need it bad.  But `(?|…|…|…)` is not widely supported, and even less widely known.  PCRE is the only other flavor I know of that supports it.

Comment: @Alan, I didn't really appreciate it much myself, because I felt it was a poor bandage that prevented people from moving on to a better solution: named captures. But I begin see it’s occasional utility, and this is a good example of that. BTW, did you notice that JDK7 looks they'll have named captures via the standard `(?<NAME>…)` and `\k<NAME>` mechanism. `.group()` will take a string argument. I don’t think they plan on making the `%+` vs `%-` distinction though, which is a trouble Python also has. It’s still cool, although it would be infinitely cooler with `(?(DEFINE)…)` blocks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
"^\[\d+\]:\s([^;]*);([^;]*)"
```

and have the host and event name in the first two capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks Jens, it worked too but the host and events are coupled, therefore, I adopted solution from Tchrist... but thanks for your reply.